# PDFBox caching in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, pdfbox

I am using Apache pdfbox for pdf file processing.

Running it locally works fine, where I get the error is on executing the code on AWS Lambda.
This makes sense as pdfbox tries to update the font cache, which is not possible on Lambda.

I get the following error massage:

```
Feb 20, 2017 3:22:19 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider loadDiskCache
WARNING: New fonts found, font cache will be re-built
Feb 20, 2017 3:22:19 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider <init>
WARNING: Building on-disk font cache, this may take a while
Feb 20, 2017 3:22:20 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider saveDiskCache
SEVERE: Could not write to font cache

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/sbx_user1063/.pdfbox.cache (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.saveDiskCache(FileSystemFontProvider.java:290)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:226)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:130)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:149)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:413)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:376)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:350)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:145)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<clinit>(PDType1Font.java:79)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:143)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetFontAndSize.process(SetFontAndSize.java:60)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:829)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:486)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:460)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:150)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.LegacyPDFStreamEngine.processPage(LegacyPDFStreamEngine.java:139)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:391)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:319)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:266)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:227)
at de.scdm.panther.ParsePdf.handleRequest(ParsePdf.java:59)
at de.scdm.panther.ParsePdf.handleRequest(ParsePdf.java:22)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:375)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:1139)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda$2.call(AWSLambda.java:94)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:285)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:57)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:94)

Feb 20, 2017 3:22:20 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider <init>
WARNING: Finished building on-disk font cache, found 52 fonts
```

How can I deactivate the font cache update?
Did someone experienced a similar problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't deactivate it, but the message is harmless, i.e. it won't stop your work. You can set the property "pdfbox.fontcache" to a directory where you can write to, e.g. /tmp . https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html does this help?

Comment: Hi Tilman, thanks for the tip. After changing the directory to /tmp, it does not throw the error message any longer! Merci

Comment: Hey Max, could you share your code for running PDFBox on Lambda? It would really save me some time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't deactivate it, but the message is harmless, i.e. it won't stop your work, but the next run won't be faster because your fonts will be looked at again.

You can set the property "pdfbox.fontcache" to a directory where you can write to, e.g. /tmp, this [should exist](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) on AWS Lambda.

PDFBox first looks at the "pdfbox.fontcache" property, if that one isn't set it will look at the "user.home" property (this is what happened on your system), if that one isn't set it will look at the "java.io.tmpdir" property to select a directory to write the font cache.